# Automator throws an error when trying to quit Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, automator

I've created a calendar event in Automator that creates and sends an email message then quits Mail. It creates and sends the message fine but then gives an error when attempting to quit Mail. I've had it running for months under Lion and recently upgraded that machine to Mountain Lion 10.8.2. The error happened under both versions. The error is -1700 which is `errAECoercionFail`. Mail isn't putting up any alerts that might keep it from quitting. Any ideas as to what would cause this?

[image: Screenshot of Automator log]

Comment: Does the menu bar item for quitting Mail also get disabled? You could try running `quit app "Mail"` in an AppleScript action instead.

Comment: Why are you waiting for three minutes before the last step?

Comment: @myhd To give Mail more than ample time to get the message sent.

Comment: If you are sure all mails are sent within 3 minutes: 1) Is there a Automator command to activate / bring Mail to the foreground? It's a long shot, but can you insert that before "Quit" command? 2) If all fails, I’m sure there is a way to quit Mail with a terminal command via Automator. Are you comfortable with this thought?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Checking the 'ask to save changes' seems to resolve the issue.